# Replacement for $() in Windows batch script

Tags: bash, batch-file

I am trying to convert my bash script into a Windows batch file. It's a really simple one liner that's supposed to feed the contents of a file as arguments to `script.exe`, and send the results to `output.txt`.

This is the working bash script:

`./script.exe $(cat input.txt) > output.txt`

I know this might be bad style, but it works. The problem is, I have no idea how to do something like `$()` in a windows batch file. When I use it it sends the string `"$(cat input.txt)"` as the argument instead of running the command.

Comment: If the unknown windows script.exe accepts redirected input, either `type input.txt|script.exe >output.txt` or `script.exe <input.txt >output.txt` otherwise you can have bash through wsl or a similar syntax with powershell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bash construct is called command substitution. Here is [a great answer from @MichaelBurr.](/a/2768660/9878263)

> You can get a similar functionality using cmd.exe scripts with the
>   `for /f` command:
>
> ```
> for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (`echo Test`) do my_command %%a
> ```
>
> Yeah, it's kinda non-obvious (to say the least), but it's what's
>   there.
>
> See `for /?` for the gory details.
>
> Sidenote: I thought that to use "`echo`" inside the backticks in a
>   "`for /f`" command would need to be done using "`cmd.exe /c echo
>   Test`" since `echo` is an internal command to `cmd.exe`, but it works
>   in the more natural way.  Windows batch scripts always surprise me
>   somehow (but not usually in a good way).

See also, on Superuser: [Is there something like Command Substitution in WIndows CLI?](//superuser.com/q/289344/is-there-something-like-command-substitution-in-windows-cli)